# How to convert UTF16 into text using php

Tags: php, utf

I have one column in DB containing UTF16 string. Right now, I want to convert the UTF16 string into normal text. How to achieve this using php?

For example:

Source : 0645 0631 062D 0628 0627 0020 0627 0644 0639 0627 0644 0645
Convert : مرحبا العالم

This [web based tools](http://macchiato.com/unicode/convert.html) works wonder but i need a php solution to integrate into my code.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you define "normal text"? Do you mean when outputting the string all you're getting is numbers?

Comment: i mean i want to get the original text before it is converted into code.

Comment: Are your database values actually "`0645 0631 ...`", or is the text `مرحبا العالم` stored as UTF-16 in the database and only comes out as numbers when you try to display it?

Comment: the database value is "0645 0631 ..."

Answer (score 0):

I picked this from [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) and can be used to convert UTF-16 hex string to UTF -8

```
function utf8_urldecode($str) {

$str = str_replace("\00", "%u00", $str);

$str = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\1;",urldecode($str));

return html_entity_decode($str,null,'UTF-8');

}
```